# Include project referenced DLL and PDB files into nuget package

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I am trying the below mentioned solution to include project referenced DLL and PDB files into a nuget package but it includes only DLLs not PDBs files.

[Including project referenced PDB files into nuget package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54129910/including-project-referenced-pdb-files-into-nuget-package)

Comment: The question you linked doesn't have an accepted answer and the comments under the only answer say that it didn't work. 

Check this guide here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages-snupkg

Comment: @Musterknabe Thanks for your reply but i don't want to create a symbol package. The above linked question is successfully including DLLs into the package. But the second part of that link which provided the solution to include PDB file also is not working for me.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. You want it to be contained in the same package, whereas the link I provided creates a different package that would be needed to be included as well, correct? What about this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41901314/2823419. The linked questions also contains different solutions